# Firing OnChange event on spelling correction in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have found some questions asked on this issue but no solution.
I have one contenteditable div in which I want Onchange event to get fired on spelling correction.I have provided sample code which I tried below:

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document.body).on("contextmenu click", function(){alert('Hi');});
</script>
```

**HTLM**

```
<body contenteditable="true" id="editor">
    < p>Please type something in here</p>
< /body>
```

I want it to work with IE11. And also want to make it clear that I don't want event to get fired on right click(for showing context menu).I want event to get fired post we click on context menu item to select the correct word.

Comment: use somehitng like this '$(document.body).on("click", "editor", function(){alert('Hi');});'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#editor").mousedown(function(e) {
    // the "which" property of the event object tells which mouse button was clicked. 3 is the right click button.
    if(e.which == 3){
        console.log("right clicked");
    }
});
```

Comment: An explanation of your solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing **Updated** answer is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};

  $("#editor").mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 )  //it will let you know is it right click or not **1** will be for left click
    {
      alert('Mouse Right button  pressed!'); 
      return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
  }); 
});
```

**Updated**  event firing on context menu hiding

```
var isIntextMenuOpen ;
$(document).on("contextmenu", function(e){

    isIntextMenuOpen = true;
});
function hideContextmenu(e){
       if(isIntextMenuOpen ){
            alert("okay")
       }

     isIntextMenuOpen = false;
}
$(window).blur(hideContextmenu);

$(document).click(hideContextmenu);
```

I have created [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/muhammadusmaann/LfetN/25/)

Comment: mousedown event will be fired when we click over a paragraph.But it will not solve my problem since I need to right click(after which context menu is opened) and click on the correct word from context menu(usual spelling correction flow).After this content of contenteditable body changes without firing onchange event in IE11. Which is my main concern.

Comment: It is firing event on right-click,but what I want is event to capture post Spelling correction.Which means I want to get event fired post we right click and select correct word from context menu for spelling correction. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I updated your fiddle to test it for my requirement 
http://jsfiddle.net/AbhiAshD/LfetN/26/

here you can click on the text,then mouseDown and mouseUp words will be underlined(misspelled words).Now right click on it and correct the words. After words gets corrected post that you will have to click again to fire the event(to get the alert in your case).Problem is when context menu is opened,window will still have focus(it will not be blurred). My requirement is to get alert immediately after we correct the words.

Comment: @Abhishek brother you can modify code according to your requirements :)